# HTML item to custom control - cognos 11.0.7

Tags: javascript, cognos

I am using cognos 11.0.7

I have one value prompt with dropdown value and a tree prompt.
What I want is to have dynamic default value (the first value) in my value prompt.

1. I successfully done this using html item with the below script and report interactivity set to `NO`. But when I set interactivity: `NO`, the tree prompt destroyed.

   ```
   <script language="javascript"> 
       var f = getFormWarpRequest(); 
       var list = f._oLstChoicesPrompt; 
       list.remove(1); 
       list.remove(0); 
       list.removeAttribute("hasLabel"); 
       list.options[0].selected = true; 
       canSubmitPrompt(); 
   </script>
   ```
2. I am trying to use custom control. I created a file `.js` using the above script (exactly the same). File uploaded in a shared path.
   I used this path in the module path. Report interactivity set to yes.

when I run the report, error appears.

```
Script error
    0
```

I click ok and another error appears

```
typeerror: _0OC is not a constructor
    at_KE4._F95 (https://.../qianalytics/bi/pat/cchl/_ke4.js:6:2582)

    at oBJECT.EXECcb (https://.../qianalytics/bi/lib/requirejs/2.1.14/require.js:1658:33)
```

and many similar records

Can someone help?
Is it ok to use the same script inside my `.js` file?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a value prompt, you have only to delete "Header Text" in prompt text options.

For a tree prompt you can use "Default Selections".

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it.

```
define( function() {
"use strict";
let arr2 = [];
function DDLSelectFirst()
{
            
};

DDLSelectFirst.prototype.initialize = function (oControlHost, fnDoneInitializing)
{
    this.m_oControlHost = oControlHost;
    this.m_DDLControl = this.getConfigurationValue("Control", "Not Set");
    if (this.m_DDLControl !== "Not Set"){
        var ctrl = this.m_oControlHost.page.getControlByName(this.m_DDLControl);
        if(ctrl && ctrl.getValues(true) &&  ctrl.getValues(true).length > 1){
        var arr = ctrl.getValues(true);
        
        arr.forEach(this.moveItem);
        }
        if(arr2.length > 0){
            ctrl.setValues(arr2);
        }
    }

    fnDoneInitializing();
};
DDLSelectFirst.prototype.moveItem = function (item) {
    if(item.use !== undefined){
    arr2.push(item);
    }
}
DDLSelectFirst.prototype.destroy = function(oControlHost)
{
    this.m_oControlHost = null;
};
DDLSelectFirst.prototype.getConfigurationValue = function (sName, sDefaultValue)
{
    var o = this.m_oControlHost.configuration;
    return ( o && ( o[sName] !== undefined ) ) ? o[sName] : sDefaultValue;
};
DDLSelectFirst.prototype.draw = function( oControlHost )
{

};
return DDLSelectFirst;
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).